# How to get element from innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access element from another element's innerHTML. I have this element:

[image]

I can clearly see the element I need inside of it. However, when I try to do this:

```
$chartContainer.find(".pin")
```

It is not found. What is the problem here?

Comment: Please add html

Comment: It's unclear why this wouldn't work. Demo (making some assumptions): https://jsfiddle.net/qwtfmxrg/ . Maybe the assumptions are wrong. Please make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can understand the issue. Adding some HTML as **text** (so it's searchable and copyable) would also be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: *"It is not found"* you mean `.find()` is not found?  `find is not a function`

Comment: my guess is `$chartContainer` is not jQuery!

Answer (score 3):

You can see from the log output that `$chartContainer` is a `HTMLDivElement` object, not a jQuery object. Therefore calling `find()` on it directly will not work. The `$` prefix on the variable name is confusing matters, so I would suggest removing it.

To fix the problem you need to wrap the `$chartContainer` in a jQuery object:

```
var $pin = $($chartContainer).find(".pin");
```

Comment: The other clue is that `.innerHTML` is not a jquery method

Comment: $($chartContainer) is no different than $chartContainer. Any other way to convert to jquery object?

Comment: `$($chartContainer) is no different than $chartContainer` yes it is, it's entirely different for reasons I explained in the above answer

Comment: @IrmantasŽelionis the next step is for you to create a snippet that reproduces the problem.  [mcve].